# Regex to extract

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want my string to always start with one of the letters A, B, C or D  followed by `\n\n` and then ending with `[,.!?]\n\n`. For example ".\n\n" or "?\n\n" or "!\n\n".

Comment: You've included the regex-group tag, do you want to include some part of the match in a group?

Comment: `^[A-D]\n{2}.*?[,.!?]\n{2}`

Comment: 'A\n\nI should have known you\'d be here,\n\nSam.\n\n'
This is my String and I want to Extract everthing from A till .\n\n

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to what you already had:

```
[ABCD]\n\n[,.!?]\n\n
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/QGoXHX/1

Comment: I want to cover everything in between. All the letters numbers and characters. It should only stop at [. ! ?]\n\n and then next sentence should again begin with [ABCD]\n\n